# Android: What happens after a HandlerThread is started?

Tags: android, android-handler, android-handlerthread

```
HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("DownloadService");
thread.start();
```

Is the looper associated with the thread waiting for a message to arrive in the message queue just **after thread.start() returns**? If so, then all I need to do is to associate the looper of this thread with a class that implements handleMessage(). Would this be the correct implementation?

Comment: yes, create a Handler associated with that Looper

Answer (score 1):

> Is the looper associated with the thread waiting for a message to arrive in the message queue just after thread.start() returns?

[Not necessarily](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java#L52). `start()` only creates a thread that will --at some point in the future-- create a [`Looper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html). `start()` itself does not wait for the looper to be ready.

**Edit:** However, this usually is not a problem, since `HandlerThread.getLooper()` will wait for the looper to be properly prepared if it is not yet ready.

Side note: I think `HandlerThread` is not a well named class, since it actually only creates a `Looper`.

Comment: no, it **is** a `Thread` (HandlerThread extends Thread), also no need to override `onLooperPrepared` see: http://androidxref.com/4.4_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/HandlerThread.java#71

Comment: I'm not complaining about the `Thread`, I'm complaining about the `Handler` since `HandlerThread` does not directly touch `Handler` in any way (`LooperThread` would have been better, maybe). Also: Read the OP's question please. There's a race condition between `start()` returning and attaching a handler in a different thread, because there may not be a `Looper` for the `HandlerThread` yet when you try to attach a handler to it.

Comment: just call: ht.start(); handler = new Handler(ht.getLooper()), that's all

Comment: To repeat myself: There's no guarantee that the Looper has already been created when you call `start()`, because the Looper is created asynchronously in the `HandlerThread`. However `getLooper()` waits for the looper to be ready.

Comment: i already did it: see the link i posted, it shows getLooper() source code, so whats wrong in `new Handler(ht.getLooper())` as `getLooper()` is a blocking method?

Comment: You are right about `getLooper()`, see edited answer. OP still asks,  if the looper is ready directly after `start()` which it isn't. It's ready after `getLooper()`, because `getLooper()` explicitly waits for it. Simply dropping links to source code is not an explanation in my book.

Comment: well, there is only one way to get HandlerThread's Looper and it is getLooper() method, so OP needs to call it anyway thus making sure that Looper is ready